# Ajax postback with Looping HTML Forms - Same Page Reloading

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I had been working on this multi-part form for my WordPress website while contains 3 forms that are loaded in a series on a single page. Form 1 is displayed first while the Form 2 and 3 are hidden. What I am doing over here is, whenever a form gets submitted, a hidden field update Form's value. And i am using if else statements to compare the values to load a specific form. So, it starts with Nil, goes on to 1 then 2 then 3. So, that's why i am calling it looping form. Sorry if i am being blunt.

Here is my Code:

```
{
    global $wpdb;

    $this_page    =   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $page     =   $_POST['page'];

    if ( $page == NULL ) {

        echo '<form method="post" action="' . $this_page .'">

            //Form Fields

            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="page" />

            <input type="submit" />

        </form>';

    }//End Page 1 of Form

    //  Start Page 2 of Form

    elseif ( $page == 1 ) {

        //  Grab the POST data that the user provided and insert it into a custom database table

        // Show Form 2 after processing data from Form 1

        echo '<form method="post" action="' . $this_page .'">

            <input type="hidden" value="' . $form_id . '" name="form_id" />//Form id - Row ID from Database

            <input type="submit" />

        </form>';

    } //End Page 2 of Form

    // Start Page 3 of Form

    elseif( $page == 2 ) {

        //Grab post data from Form 2 and append it to the same database table. (Check against Form ID to find the same row)

        //Show Form 3 after processing form 2

        echo '<form method="post" action="' . $this_page .'"> 

            //Form 3 Fields

            <input type="hidden" value="3" name="page" />

            <input type="hidden" value="' . $form_id . '" name="form_id" />

            <input type="submit" />

        </form>';

    }

    // Start Page 4 of Form

    if ( $page == 3 ) {

        //Process Form 3

        //Show Thanks Message

        echo "<h3>Thanks so much!</h3>";

    }// End Page 4 of Form

};
```

The code above works without any issues and perfectly doing what i want it to do.

The problem i am having is, it reloads the whole page to process the current form and load the next part of the form. I want to do this without reloading the whole page.

In layman's terms, i have though of two approaches:

1. Using Ajax / Jquery
2. Using iframes to reload just a section(Div) containing that form.

After spending a lot of time doing research, i found out some little details for implementing the Method 1.

Here is what i have found:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Link to the Same File.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: content
});
```

But i definitely know that this isnt complete. I still tried to implement this but as expected, it didn't work out.

I would just like to reload either a specific section of page which is containing the form or submit forms using ajax and would like to know if it is possible to do. Please let me know.

Looking forward to your response.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax with WordPress is slightly different, this link may help you out.

http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

Place the `PHP` part in this example, into your theme's `functions.php` .